# Can't get Ghostscript to use OpenType fonts

Tags: windows, pdf, ghostscript, opentype

I am trying to use GhostScript 9.27 on Windows to turn some PDF files into PDF/A files. However, an installed font gets replaced with Helvetica even though it should be available from the system's font directory.

This is the relevant section of the debug output:

```
%Resolving: [7 0]
resmp ResourceStatus beg /RotisSansSerifStd-Regular
cidcm GetCIDSystemInfo beg
resmp ResourceStatus beg /RotisSansSerifStd
resmp ResourceFileName beg RotisSansSerifStd
resmp ResourceFileName : have NO map record.
resmp ResourceFileName : retrieving %rom%Resource/CIDFont/RotisSansSerifStd
resmp ResourceFileName end
resmp ResourceStatus end
cidcm GetCIDSystemInfo end
resmp ResourceStatus end
```

As far as I know, Ghostscript should work with otf fonts and I wonder why "NO map record" is found when this is what I added to `Fontmap.GS`:

```
/RotisSansSerifStd          (C:\Windows\Fonts\RotisSansSerifStd-Regular.otf)    ;
/RotisSansSerifStd,Bold         (C:\Windows\Fonts\RotisSansSerifStd-Bold.otf)   ;
/RotisSansSerifStd-Regular      (C:\Windows\Fonts\RotisSansSerifStd-Regular.otf)    ;
/RotisSansSerifStd-Bold         (C:\Windows\Fonts\RotisSansSerifStd-Bold.otf)   ;
```

What am I donig wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot (currently) use an OTF font with CFF outlines as a substitute for a missing CIDFont, you can use an OTF font with TrueType outlines. I believe you can use an OTF font with CFF outlines as a substitute for a missing Font.

Your PDF file appears to be missing a CIDFont (it would have helped to see the all the output from GS but without RESMPDEBUG set), you are modifying fontmap.GS which only defines substittues for missing Fonts, not CIDFonts. You would to need to modify cidfmap rather than fontmap.GS in order to define a subsitute for a missing CIDFont.

As far as I can see, the "no map record" warning is entirely correct, there is no map record in cidfmap for the named CIDFont.